# How to say less than but no equal to in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm getting an error with this, I did my research but found nothing.

```
if [ $value -lt 3 -ne 1 ]; then
execute code
fi
```

```
line 6: [: syntax error: -ne unexpected
```

Comment: try `-le` (less or equal) instead of `-lt` (less than). And `man test` might give you some additional information

Comment: See: `help test`

Comment: `[ "$value" -lt 3 ] && [ "$value" -ne 1 ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make this work is

```
if [ "${value}" -lt 3 ] && [ "${value}" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Hello"
fi
```

Comment: Needs more quotes to be correct. `[ "$value" -lt 3 ] && [ "$value" -ne 1 ]` -- without the quotes you'll git incorrect/misleading error messages when `value` doesn't contain a single number.

Comment: ...or even incorrect results. Consider the case where `value='1 = 1 -o 99'` -- it'll always be true with your original code, even though 99 is not less than 3 and also `value` _should_ fail to parse as a number at all.

Answer (score 2):

I like to switch to arithmetic expressions using `((` when I need tests like these:

```sh
declare -a values=(1 2 3)

for value in "${values[@]}"; do
  if (( value != 1 && value < 3 )); then
    echo "execute code for $value"
  fi
done
```

The above outputs:

```
execute code for 2
```

Answer (score 0):

use (( )) brackets for arithmetic operations and [[ ]] for strings comparison
$ is redundant in round brackets so (( $a == 1 )) is the same as (( a == 1 ))

typeset a=2

(( a < 3  )) && (( a != 1 )) && echo "Execute code"

more details : http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/unix_sg/bash/math.html

Comment: Does this include anything not already covered in the preexisting answer by Ionut G. Stan?

Comment: BTW, there _is_ a practical difference between `(( $a == 1 ))` and `(( a == 1 ))`: The former will emit an error when `a` is an empty string; the latter will treat it as 0.

Comment: thx, you are right 
a=""
$ (( $a == 1 )) && echo "Test"
bash: ((: == 1 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "== 1 ")